# Writing a program in CodeBlocks -> power outage -> program corrupted

Tags: codeblocks, restore, corrupt

For the last couple of weeks i've been writing a program in CodeBlocks and today i had a power outage. In CodeBlocks the main.cpp file showed up as empty, but in Notepad++ it shows up as a lot of NUL characters and explorer it says that it has a size of 295 KB.
This kind of thing didn't happen to me before so, of course, i didn't have any extra backup program of feature turned on. I tried to look if i had any previous versions of the .cpp file saved and if windows made a system restore in the last couple of days, but with no luck. I have pretty much all the default setting on CodeBlocks.
Any help with restoring the file, if possible, would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Regardless of whether you succeed restoring the file or not, take this event as a sign that you should start using version control. Git is a popular choice. If you followed the best practices, most you'd lose is a few hours of work (whatever was not yet committed).

Comment: Also consider investing in a UPS.